# recieving and sending messages to a specific category(discord bot)

Tags: python, discord

Included below is also my message object
Here is my code for specific channel and it works:

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
    
    msg = message.content
    msg = msg.lower()
    if message.channel.name == "name" and msg.startswith('bruh'):
        await message.channel.send('hello')```
#Here is what I tried with specific category:
    if message.category.name == "name" and msg.startswith('bruh'):
        await message.channel.send('hello')`
#Error:AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'category', I also tried with message.category.id and got the same error
#I want the bot to receive a command in a specific category and return a message in that category and to the channel where it received the command.
````

Comment: Please provide more code. How you create a message object?

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: What is `message` object type? How you init it? I mean before you pass it as an argument tot the function `on_message `

Comment: It is not init before that is where it's first mentioned, sorry I'm a bit confused at what your asking

Comment: Can you log type of an object? If it's a specific object from some library, then proveide a version of a library and probably your python version

Comment: What is a "category"? You can see in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) that `category` does not exist for `Message`.